# Getting Error: Please make sure to specify the 'deviceName' capability in Appium v1.0.0

Tags: java, ios, automation, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am unable to run my script neither on device nor on simulator.
It gives the following error :

```
error: Could not determine your device from Appium arguments or desired capabilities. 
Please make sure to specify the 'deviceName' capability
```

It was working earlier with Appium v0.18.2 but when I updated it to v1.0.0 - Orion , it's giving this error.

I tried with :

```
[1] capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone Simulator");

[2] capabilities.setCapability("device", "iPhone Simulator");    

[3] capabilities.setCapability("device", "iPhone");  

[4] capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone");
```

My other capabilties are set as below :

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "iOS");

capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "7.1");

capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Mac"); 

capabilities.setCapability("app", "/Users/smriti/Abc.app");

driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Where need to set this deviceName.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can we please have an excepted answer here

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify both device name

```
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone Simulator");
```

and platform name

```
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "iOS");
```

See the [migration docs](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/migrating-to-1-0.md#new-desired-capabilities) and the [1.0 desired capabilities](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/caps.md)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void androidSetup() {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.android();
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Samsung");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", System.getProperty("deviceOS"));
        capabilities.setCapability("app", System.getProperty("user.dir") + ".apk file");
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "package name");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "Activity name");
        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        //driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:" + System.getProperty("environment") + "/wd/hub"), capabilities);

    }

    public static void iosSetup() throws MalformedURLException{
        File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "/build/");
        File app = new File(appDir, ".ipa file");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName","iOS");
        capabilities.setCapability("udid","2dc3bf20559d41565d9f1fd08f738183d9a54ead");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.4");
        capabilities.setCapability("bundleId","com.xyz");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Brattys");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
        driver = new IOSDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }
```